# Custom Sort in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to custom sort a list using App Script for Google Sheets, basically I have a list of the months and I want them to appear as January, February, March... in the order of the months. This is an example of my list

[image]

The code I used in App Script is:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var values = range.getValues(); 

  var sortBy = {
    "January": 1,
    "February": 2,
    "March": 3,
    "April": 4,
    "May": 5,
    "June": 6,
    "July": 7,
    "August": 8,
    "September": 9,
    "October": 10,
    "November": 11,
    "December": 12
  };

values.sort(function(a,b){
  return sortBy[[a][0]] - sortBy[[b][0]];
});
```

How can I connect this code in App Script to my spreadsheet for the months to get sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
values.sort(([a],[b]) => sortBy[a] - sortBy[b]);

range.setValues(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Sort Months

```
 function sortMonths() {
  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(),x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), x , 1),Session.getScriptTimeZone,"MMMM"))];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().sort((a,b) => {
    let vA = mA.indexOf(a[0]);
    let vB = mA.indexOf(b[0]);
    return vA-vB;//swap for descending
  });//Data in column A
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)